# Insert or Update self-signed cert into Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, devops, self-signed

I am aware, self signed cert should be written in docker file etc:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
COPY <my path>/<cert name>.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/<cert name>.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

I decided to remove the above mentioned line of codes (line 2 and 3) and intend to install the crt as follows:

In the power shell

```
docker cp <location of the .crt> <image id>:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/<filename>.crt
```

Go to the docker image's CLI and, in /app, run

```
update-ca-certificates
```

And then restart the affected container.

I tried to curl the link. I encounter this error:

```
curl: (77) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
```

What are steps I've missed? I also have install the .pfx in the trusted root and the container is running in Linux.

Also anyone mind sharing how one updates their crt in docker container when the crt is about to expiry?

Comment: The error message is clear. I suspect your CA certificate is not valid and I would try to convert it to .crt.

Comment: It is in.crt as I’ve generated using openssl what’s interesting is that the crt are able to execute in docker file but I cant copy manually?